# Postback en ASP net MVC 5 no funciona luego de un JsonResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hacer un postback en jsonresult ya que uso un modal para eliminar en mvc 5 pero no realiza un postback..

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Eliminar(int id)
    {
        cargo carg = db.cargo.Where(x => x.idcargo == id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.cargo.Remove(carg);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

---codigo en script

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.eliminar').click(function () {
            var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $("#btnEliminar").attr("data-eliminar", idEliminar);
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
        $("#btnEliminar").click(function () {
            var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-eliminar");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/cargo/Eliminar',
                type: 'get',
                data: { id: idEliminar },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("Exito");
                    $("#" + idEliminar).remove();
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("fallo");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué has intentado?¿Dónde está el HTML, JavaScript que usas?¿Cuál es el comportamiento que esperas del código mostrado?¿En qué momento debe haber un postback?¿Cuál es el escenario? Bienvenido al sitio, date una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio. Saludos :D

Comment: este es el java script que utilizo en la BD elimina si recargo la pagina me muestra que me elimino lo que deseo es actualizar la pagina cuando se ejecute

Comment: es decir, la eliminación funciona bien. Lo que quieres es un "refresh", cierto?

Comment: si la eliminacion funciona pero no recarga la pagina, correcto el refresh de la pagina

Comment: basado en lo que dices, acabo de responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#btnEliminar").click(function () {
            var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-eliminar");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/cargo/Eliminar',
                type: 'get',
                data: { id: idEliminar },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("Exito");
                    $("#" + idEliminar).remove();
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    //Esto le dará el refresh a tu página:  
                    window.location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("fallo");
                }
            });
        });
```

Por cierto, los postbacks son cosas de WebForms, ASP.net MVC trabaja mejor con JavaScript.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias lo probare

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir :D